# Python — Extract edge loops (array of 2D points) from simple raster shapes

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, vectorization, geospatial

I would be very thankful if you could help me with the question. I have a raster image with simple shapes of random color on it. For simplicity, we can assume that the background is pure white, the shapes don't have intersections or common edges, they are always of uniform color with hard edges, no transparency used. So, basically, just various shapes of random geometry.

What I need at the end is to get the loops of 2D points (where coordinates can be simply pixel coordinates from the original image) describing the edge of each shape. Example of output:

```
Shape 1: [(373, 156), (351, 167) (322, 181), (299, 201), ...]
Shape 2: [(1011, 74), (998, 94) (973, 112), (952, 145), ...]
```

An additional extremely useful feature would be to set the "sensitivity" of the algorithm which would affect the accuracy, precision, and density of the extracted loops. In other words, if the "sensitivity" is low, the created loops should be of quite "low-resolution", be angular, and consist of a low amount of points; but if the "sensitivity" is high, the created loops should be of "high-resolution", be nice and smooth, and consist of a high amount of points.

The picture is worth a thousand words, therefore, here I drew a simple demonstration:
[image]

I spent quite a lot of time trying to find how to do that and it seems like I probably need to "vectorize" it or use NumPy and some library for geospatial data but really I'm a little lost at the moment and would be happy to get advice on how to do that. I feel like the solution shouldn't be that hard because I look at those really amazing things and examples libraries like NumPy and GDAL can do and I'm sure these or similar libraries can solve my task without any difficulties.

**Thank you** very much for your time!

Comment: You should be able to use OpenCV or scikit-image well for this purpose. This is generally known as "contour detection" where a "contour" is the outline of a shape as a polygon/list of points. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html for tutorials. For fewer points, you can approximate the polygon via Douglas-Peucker, also provided in these libs: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_polygon.html and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: @alkasm Wooooow! Thank you very very very very much! You cannot imagine how thankful I am to you! This is exactly what I needed. I looked at those examples and I was able to implement a prototype in 30 minutes that does exactly what I need. You are absolutely AMAZING!

Comment: @alkasm Excuse me for a silly question but is it possible to make your comment an accepted answer? You really hit the nail here, therefore, your answer can be useful for other people.